# Veracode issue CWE 915

Tags: asp.net-web-api, veracode

I'm having a POST method in my ASP.NET core web API which takes a model as a parameter (binding POST content directly to model). The model contains all the parameters as optional parameters. While scanning the web service using Veracode, I get flaw-1 with CSE 915 (Insufficient input validation for ErrorReporter Service reasons.) which is the possible scenario for MVC EF application.

I have gone through the [article](https://igormsouza.wordpress.com/2017/11/14/veracode-scan-how-to-solve-cwe-915-issues-in-asp-net-mvc-project/). It is saying to use Bind attribute with Include and Exclude properties. But in my case, I don't have any parameter which is mandatory to pass in the model.

Is there any alternative to resolve this or any attribute using which I can remove the Veracode scan for this specific method in the code itself.

Comment: I have the same problem, also using ASP.NET Core web api. I have tried adding the [Bind] attribute to the parameter of my controller action, but I still get the warning. I hate Veracode.

Comment: I resolved this issue by choosing "Mitigate by Design" on the Veracode report, and writing that my request uses a viewmodel so it is not an issue.

Comment: Yeah, for now, I have mitigated the issue as it will not exploit in our case but I just wanted to know what could be the possible solutions to resolve this. @MattFrear

Answer (score -2):

**Insufficient Input Validation is caused by using the user input directly to take decisions and it can be overcome by sanitizing the taken input.**

```
var userInput = new Sanitize(userInput).Value;
```

This Sanitize method could be put in appropriate class of your project

```
public Sanitize(dynamic input)
{
    string inputValue = Convert.ToString(input);
    Value = inputValue.Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "");
}
```